# error: Generic parameter 'R.Generator.Element' cannot be bound to non-@objc protocol type 'AnyObject'

Tags: ios

I am querying HealthKit and saving it to CoreData.  I fetch the data in a separate class. In TableViewController I append the data to an array:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("weightSwitch") == true {
    xAxisDatesArray.append(cdFetchWeight.queryCoreDataDate())
    yAxisValuesArray.append(cdFetchWeight.queryCoreDataData())
```

and pass it at tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

```
myCell.xAxisDates = xAxisDatesArray[indexPath.row]
myCell.yAxisValues = yAxisValuesArray[indexPath.row]
```

In UITableViewCell I initialise the variables (yAxisValues, xAxisDates) and pass them into a charting library which takes the x and y values and plot a chart.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, TKChartDelegate {

    var xAxisDates = []
    var yAxisValues = []

    plot....
```

I need to get the min and max values of yAxisValues so that I can set the appropriate y-axis range to the data.

I have tried to get the min and max with the following code:

```
func rangeMinAndMax(){
    let minYvalue = minElement(yAxisValues)
    let maxYvalue = maxElement(yAxisValues)
}
```

But this generates the error: Generic parameter 'R.Generator.Element' cannot be bound to non-@objc protocol type 'AnyObject'

**- Question: Why and how can I fix it?**

Any help would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing to do in a situation like this is to throw away all the misleading dross and boil it down to the simplest possible case:

```
let arr : [AnyObject] = [1,2,3]
let min = minElement(arr) // same error: "Generic parameter blah-de-blah..."
```

So, you see, `minElement` doesn't work on an array of AnyObject, and that's what the error is telling you. And the reason is obvious: an AnyObject is not a Comparable. There is no "minimum" for a bunch of AnyObject things; the entire concept of one AnyObject being "less than" another AnyObject is undefined. You need to cast your array down to an array of something that `minElement` can work on, namely a Comparable of some kind.

For example, in that code, I can fix the problem like this:

```
let arr : [AnyObject] = [1,2,3]
let min = minElement(arr as [Int])
```

That is the sort of thing you need to be doing. Of course, what you cast down to depends upon what these elements actually are. It looks to me as if will probably be Double and NSDate respectively, but that's just a guess; I don't know what's in your arrays. You do (presumably). Note that an NSDate is not a Comparable so you will have a bit more work to do with that one.

Comment: Really nice answer and a good tip to boil down the problem, I now understand how you read the error message.  But for me it did not make much sense because my CoreData Type is Double, but I guess the AnyObject Type from HealthKit was passed through?  Or that the Double was made into AnyObject somewhere else in my code? Thank You :-)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been a bit clearer. Everything coming back from Objective-C into Swift as an array is an array of AnyObject to start with. It isn't HealthKit or Core Data, it's the whole Objective-C -> Swift bridge. The reason is that Swift arrays specify their element types, but Objective-C NSArrays do not. So Swift has to pick _some_ element type, and an AnyObject is the same as an `id` so it works. I didn't realize that it might be important to say that explicitly.